# JSON devuelve valores incorrectos

Tags: json, nodejs, express, docker, docker-compose

Tuve que modificar debido a que no puse todo el proceso de error, aqui va el proceso desde que los datos estan en la pagina y se envian a la api.

tengo una pagina hecha en angular5 y se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo tiene un input, el cual se le ingresa un código y un botón. El botón llama a una función que hace lo siguiente:

```
  refund() {
    this._dash.refund(this.id).subscribe(
      ok => {
        this.id = new Refund('');
        const cod = ok['estado'];
        console.log(cod);
        if (cod === 0) {
          this.err = false;
          this.ale = false;
          this.suc = true;
          this.mensaje = ok['mensaje'];
        } else if (cod === 5 || cod === 7 || cod === 9 || cod === 2) {
          this.suc = false;
          this.err = false;
          this.ale = true;
          this.mensaje = ok['mensaje'];
        } else if (cod === 3 || cod === 4) {
          this.suc = false;
          this.ale = false;
          this.err = true;
          this.mensaje = ok['mensaje'];
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Mi función hace uso de un servicio y de un modal que hace la petición post a una api hecha en nodejs. Mi servicio esta estructurado así:

```
  refund_service( refund: any ) {

    const peso = refund;
    const json = JSON.stringify(refund);
    const params = json;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.post(this.url + 'refundDebtBase', params, { headers });

  }
```

Y mi modal esta hecho así:

```
export class Refund {
    constructor(
        public transaction_id: string
    ) {}

}
```

Y finalmente este sera la estructura base de la función que se encuentra en mi api hecha en nodeJS, que recibe como parametro un JSON

```
const refundDebtBase = async(req, res) => {

}
```

cuando presento los valores de `req.body` con `console.log(req.body)` el JSON luce perfecto, obteniendo lo sieguiente `{ transaction_id: 'DF-178502' }`.

Hasta ese punto todo esta perfecto, sin embargo cuando intento obtener el valor de `DF` presentandolo en consola `console.log(req.body.transaction_id)` solo me devuelve el ultimo valor, en este caso seria el `2`, intente ponerlo en minúscula `console.log(req.body.transaction_id)` pero solo me devuelve el primer valor, en este caso seria la `D`.

He usado el método `JSON.stringify` con `req.body` presente valores y obtiene los mismo resultados, todo eso luego lo puse dentro del método `JSON.parse` pero no tengo ningún cambio, también hice todo lo anterior intentando almacenarlo dentro de una variable, pero todo sigue igual.

Al presentar `console.log(typeof req.body)`, me indica que es un `Object`.

Espero puedan ayudarme con ese problema, sin mas que decir me despido de cada uno de usted. Gracias por la ayuda.

```
================================================================================================
    /*req.body*/
    { transaction_id: 'DF-178502' }
    ================================================================================================
    /*req.body.transaction_id*/

    2
    ================================================================================================
    /*typeof req*/
    object
    ================================================================================================
    /*typeof req.body*/
    object
    ================================================================================================
    /*typeof req.body.transaction_id*/
    string
    ================================================================================================
```

E intentado haciendo uso del metodo cadena.substr(1, cadena.length -2), pero seguía obteniendo solo el 8, luego hice un recorrido para obtener el valor de cada posición de la cadena y almacenarla en una arreglo y luego usar las posiciones del arreglo que no tiene las comillas, pero al momento de imprimir el arreglo para ver los datos, noto que se a almacenado un poco de incoherencias, realmente estoy perdido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece un poco raro que cuando haces `console.log(req.body)` te ponga `{ DF: 'DF-178502' }` con comillas simples en vez de comillas dobles y que te indique que el tipo es un `Object`. ¿En qué navegador estás probando? ¿Puedes volver a ejecutar estos comandos `console.log(req); console.log(req.body); console.log(req.body.DF); console.log(typeof req); console.log(typeof req.body); console.log(typeof req.body.DF);` y pegar los resultados?

Comment: @ordago por su puesto, acabo de poner los cambios en mi pregunta, si embargo los datos de console.log(req) es muy extenso por lo que no pude poner el resultado. Si aun lo necesitas me avisas. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Estoy flipando con el problema este. Te hago una respuesta porque no me cabe en el comentario

Comment: @LuisAlava por favor si necesitas ampliar tu pregunta con mas información debes hacerlo en tu publicación original, no en la respuesta de quien te esta auxiliando por favor

Comment: @Aprendiz  mil disculpa, aun no tengo mucha experiencia aquí

Comment: Esta línea: `tem.substr(i,i);` no hace lo que crees, y el resultado mostrado en la imágen es correcto. Puedes leer la documentación de [String.prototype.substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substr). Lo que debes escribir es `tem.substr(i,1);`, ya que el segundo parámetro de `substr` indica la cantidad de caracteres devueltos o extraídos del `string`, empezando en el índice marcado por `i`. Prueba eso y comenta. Saludos

Comment: te comento que realice lo que me indicas, sin embargo el ultimo valor me daba con inconveniente, sin embargo ya no tengo el problema, cual era el inconvenientes? realmente no lo pude encontrar, simplemente pase de producción a desarrollo hice pruebas y todo salio bien. Lo envié de vuelta a producción y ya no dio error :s

Answer (score 0):

No me cabía como comentario así que lo pongo como respuesta, aunque realmente son dudas para OP. ¿El objeto request tiene alguna función get asociada a la propiedad DF que pueda estar interfiriendo? Te pongo un ejemplo, si yo defino esta variable:

```
var a = { "DF": "DF-178502" }
console.log(a.DF); // Salida -> DF-178502
```

Pero si le añado una funcion get puedo cambiar lo que me devuelve a.DF:

```
var a = { "DF": "DF-178502", get DF() { return "XXX"} }
console.log(a.DF); // Salida -> XXX
```

Puedes ver si tiene alguna función get si escribes en la consola la variable y la despliegas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pues no, no tienes ninguna función get, es mas le cambien el nombre de la variable DF por transaction_id y sigo teniendo los mismo resultados, en breve pondré todo el proceso, para que se entienda mejor, puede que este enviando mal los datos desde mi pagina a la api.

Comment: @LuisAlava es de lo mas raro que he visto. ¿Obtienes lo mismo si haces console.log y alert? ¿Puede que se haya redefinido esa función? ¿Puedes sacar capturas de pantalla de lo que te saca por consola desplegándolo? ¿Puedes sacar capturas de lo que te devuelve el servicio en la pestaña de network en el inspector de tu navegador?

Comment: acabo de añadir la foto por consola desplegandola, sobre lo del servicio, el servicio espera que la api responda, mi api, se conecta con una api de un proveedor, como el código se envía con las comillas, el proveedor me indica que no encuentra ese codigo registrado, y yo envio un mensaje al servicio indicando que no se pudo realizar la operación. Intente hacer otras cosas, acabo de modificar mi pregunta